# local variable value is no passed to promise return function in protractor using bluebird

Tags: angularjs, protractor, bluebird

```
var index = 0;
sc.getCaseNumber().then(function (text) {
  console.log("dddddddddddd" + text);
  for (var i = 0; i <= caseCount; i++) {
    var expectedPendingCases = casenum.summaries[i].urn;
    console.log("case " + expectedPendingCases);

    if (text == expectedPendingCases) {
      console.log("inside--------1 " + text);
      expect(text).toEqual(expectedPendingCases);
      index = i + 1;
      sjpCasesPendingDecisionPage.getSearchCaseNumber(index).then(function (text) {
        console.log("inside loop" + text);
      });

      break;
    }
    }

});
console.log("Index--------"+index);
return promise.props({
  urn: sc.getSearchCaseNumber(index)
   aDays: sc.getSearchAgeDays(index),
   prosec: sc.getSearchprosecutor(index),
   plea: sc.getSearchReadyForDecision(index)
});
```

I am trying to match a case number with data in expectedPendingCases and 
get the index value and find all the  elements using this index value and return the promise 
however , 
    index value is defaulted to 0 even when the index value is changed 
    this value is not reflected in 
    return promise.props({
      urn: sc.getSearchCaseNumber(index)